# How to create plot on python, spyder

Tags: python

I need to generate data and save it on a file in a directory, both are created at run time. "File Not Found error" occurs

I have some data which is created as below method

```py
log = AnalyzeLog()
```

then I need to save that data in a file with .csv extension in the directory, both the directory and file supposed to be created at run time using the below code but I am not been able to create both...

```py
plot_data_path = "E:\\Malicious_TLS_Detection-master\\M_TLS_Detection\\dataset\\data_model"    

dir_name=dataset0

for dir_name in normal_folder_path:
        path_to_single = normal_path + "\\" + dir_name
        __PrintManager__.single_folder_header(path_to_single)
        log.evaluate_features(path_to_single)
        __PrintManager__.succ_single_folder_header()
        log.create_plot_data(plot_data_path, dir_name)


def create_plot_data(self, path, filename):
        __PrintManager__.evaluate_creating_plot()
        self.create_dataset(path, filename)
        __PrintManager__.succ_evaluate_data()

 def create_dataset(self, path, filename):
        index = 0
        ssl_flow = 0
        all_flow = 0
        malicious = 0
        normal = 0
        # file header: label feature
        header = [\
        'label',\        
        'avg_domain_name_length',\
        'std_domain_name_length',\
        'avg_IPs_in_DNS']
        with open(
                path + "\\dataset-" + filename + ".csv", 'w+',
                newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(header)
            for key in self.conn_tuple:
                label_feature = [\
                str(self.conn_tuple[key].is_malicious()),\
                length()),\
                str(self.conn_tuple[key].avg_IPs_in_DNS())]
                writer.writerow(label_feature)

        print("<<< dataset file dataset-%s.csv successfully created !" %
              filename)
```

The code just breaks at

```py
 with open(
                path + "\\dataset-" + filename + ".csv", 'w+',
                newline='') as f:

path=E:\\Malicious_TLS_Detection-master\\M_TLS_Detection\\dataset\\data_model

filename=dataset0
```

Data in the csv format must be created in a file but the following error arises

"No such file or directory: 'E:\Malicious_TLS_Detection-master\M_TLS_Detection\dataset\data_model\dataset-dataset0.csv'"

Comment: I don't think, we can say anything here, until seeing what the methods, you are using, do

Comment: I have placed the required code..."create_plot_date" calls "create_dataset" and in that method code breaks...

Comment: Does the directory `E:\Malicious_TLS_Detection-master\M_TLS_Detection\dataset\data_model` exist? If not you need to create it before you can `open` a file in it.